# Background colored column headers in a pdf apex page without using pageblocktable

Tags: apex, class, pdf, styleclass

I have a requirement to show colored backgrounds for column headers of tables. Can someone suggest a way out without using pageblocktable?

Please find my controller class here.

```
public class IncidentDetailExtnController{
    Incident__c oInc {get;set;}
    Id recId;
    public List<Incident_Transaction__c> oIncTranListHCPDetail {get;set;}
    public List<Incident_Transaction__c> oIncTranListHCI {get;set;}
    public List<Incident_Transaction__c> oIncTranListPharmacy{get;set;}
    public List<Incident_Transaction__c>oIncTranListHCPSamples{get;set;}
    public List<Incident_Transaction__c>oIncTranListHCPSpeaker{get;set;}
        public List<Incident_Transaction__c>oIncTranListSynch{get;set;}
    public String profName{get;set;}
    public Map<id,String> MapIncTxn{get;set;}
        public Boolean k{get;set;}
    public IncidentDetailExtnController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        recId =ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
        oInc = (Incident__c) controller.getRecord();
        oIncTranListHCPDetail = [SELECT Account_Abs_abv__c,Account_Location_abv__c,Attendee_Role_abv__c ,Prof_City_abv__c,Prof_zip_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name,Account_Name_abv__c ,
                                Call_Detail_abv__c , Call_Detail_abv__r.Product_vod__c ,Prof_Address_Line2_abv__c, Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__c , Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Call_Date_vod__c , 
                                Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c , Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Associated_Prescriber_CIA__r.Name , Prof_state_abv__c,
                                Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Account_vod__r.Name , Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Address_vod__c , Call_Detail_abv__r.Type_vod__c , 
                                Call_Sample_abv__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Account_vod__r.Name , Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Activity_Type__c , 
                                Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Address_vod__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c , id,
                                Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Associated_Prescriber_CIA__r.Name , Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Call_Date_vod__c , 
                                Call_Sample_abv__r.Quantity_vod__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Product_vod__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Product_vod__r.Product_Type_vod__c , 
                                Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c , Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c , Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c , Outcome_abv__c , Transaction_type__c , Call__c , 
                                Call__r.Account_vod__r.Name , Call__r.Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c , Call__r.Associated_Prescriber_CIA__r.Name , Call__r.Call_Date_vod__c , 
                                Call__r.Address_vod__c, Call__r.Detailed_Products_vod__c,Prof_First_Name_abv__c,Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c,Prof_Last_Name_abv__c,Prof_Address_Line1_abv__c
                                 FROM Incident_Transaction__c where Incident__c = :recId and Transaction_type__c=:'HCP Calls'];


              oIncTranListHCI = [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Location_abv__c, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c, Call__c, Call_Detail_abv__c, Call_Sample_abv__c, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident__c, Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Prof_Address_Line1_abv__c, Prof_Address_Line2_abv__c
            ,Prof_City_abv__c ,Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, Prof_State_abv__c, Prof_Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, Transaction_type__c 
            FROM Incident_Transaction__c where Incident__c = :recId and Transaction_type__c=:'HIC/HCO Calls'];
            //Type =Pharmacy
            oIncTranListPharmacy= [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c, Account_Location_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c, Call__c, Call_Detail_abv__c, Call_Sample_abv__c, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident__c, Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Prof_Address_Line1_abv__c, Prof_Address_Line2_abv__c, Prof_City_abv__c, Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, Prof_State_abv__c, Prof_Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, Transaction_type__c 
            FROM Incident_Transaction__c where Incident__c = :recId and Transaction_type__c=:'Pharmacy Calls'];

            oIncTranListHCPSamples = [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c, Account_Location_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c, Call__c, Call_Detail_abv__c, Call_Sample_abv__c, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident__c, Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Prof_Address_Line1_abv__c, Prof_Address_Line2_abv__c, Prof_City_abv__c, Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, Prof_State_abv__c, Prof_Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, Transaction_type__c 
            FROM Incident_Transaction__c where Incident__c = :recId and Transaction_type__c=:'Samples'];

            oIncTranListHCPSpeaker = [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Location_abv__c, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c, Call__c, Call_Detail_abv__c, Call_Sample_abv__c, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident__c, Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Prof_Address_Line1_abv__c, Prof_Address_Line2_abv__c, Prof_City_abv__c, Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, Prof_State_abv__c, Prof_Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, Transaction_type__c 
            FROM Incident_Transaction__c where Incident__c = :recId and Transaction_type__c=:'Speaker Program Attendees'];

            oIncTranListSynch = [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Location_abv__c, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c, Call__c, Call_Detail_abv__c, Call_Sample_abv__c, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident__c, Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Prof_Address_Line1_abv__c, Prof_Address_Line2_abv__c, Prof_City_abv__c, Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, Prof_State_abv__c, Prof_Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, Transaction_type__c 
            FROM Incident_Transaction__c where Incident__c = :recId and Transaction_type__c=:'Synch Rate report'];



   Map<id,String> MapIncTxn= new Map<id,String>();   

   for(   Incident_Transaction__c IT :oIncTranListHCPDetail )
   {
   profName=IT.Prof_First_Name_abv__c+' '+IT.Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c+' '+IT.Prof_Last_Name_abv__c;
   MapIncTxn.put(IT.id,profName);

   }


    }   //constr ends  
    public PageReference attest()
    {

        return null;
    }   
}
```

Apex page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Incident__c" extensions="IncidentDetailExtnController" renderAs="pdf"  applyBodyTag="false">
<html>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
  .TableTitle {
    background-color: red!important; 
    font-size:100% !important; 
  }

</style>
</html>
   <apex:pageBlock title="Incident Detail">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Incident__c.Name}"  styleClass="TableTitle"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Incident__c.Rep_Lookup_id__c}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Incident__c.Report_Publish_date__c}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Incident__c.Status_abv__c}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Incident__c.No_Of_Transactions_abv__c}"/>                                                
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>   

    <apex:pageBlock title="Incident Transactions">
        <!--<apex:tabPanel switchType="client">-->

            <!--<apex:tab label="HCP Calls">
            <a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" target="_blank">Tutorials Point</a>
            <!--<a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" target="_blank">Tutorials Point</a>
            <a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" target="_self">Tutorials Point</a>--!-->


           <!-- <apex:tab label="Samples">
            <a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" target="_self">Tutorials Point</a>
            </apex:tab>
            <apex:tab label="Speaker Program Attendees">

            </apex:tab>
            <apex:tab label="Synch Rate">

            </apex:tab>                               
        </apex:tabPanel>-->


        <apex:pageBlockSection title="HCP Calls"  collapsible="true">
        <apex:pageBlockTable columns="9" value="{!oIncTranListHCPDetail}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Professional Name" styleClass="TableTitle" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c} {!itr.Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c} {!itr.Prof_Last_Name_abv__c}" />

         <!-- Need to put Profname string here from the map -->
        <apex:column headerValue=" ABS on Call" styleClass="TableTitle"/> 
        <apex:column value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" /> 
        <apex:column headerValue=" Professional Address" />
        <apex:column value="{!itr.Prof_Address_Line1_abv__c}" /> 
        <apex:column headerValue=" Associated Prescriber" value="{!itr.Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue=" Product" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue=" Activity Date" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" /> 
        <apex:column headerValue=" Outcome - LOV" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />



        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Samples" columns="4">
        <apex:pageBlockTable columns="10" value="{!oIncTranListHCPDetail}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Sample Type" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Professional Name" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c} {!itr.Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c}  {!itr.Prof_Last_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="ABS on Call" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Professional Address" value="{!itr.Prof_Address_Line1_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Product" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Activity Date" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Quantity (for hand samples, ESR, and DTP/BRC tied to rep)" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Speaker Program Attendees" columns="4">

         <apex:pageBlockTable columns="9" value="{!oIncTranListHCPDetail}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Professional Name" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c} {!itr.Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c}  {!itr.Prof_Last_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="ABS on Call" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Professional Address" value="{!itr.Prof_Address_Line1_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Product" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Activity Date" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Program Name, Date and Location" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Synch report" columns="4">

         <apex:pageBlockTable columns="6" value="{!oIncTranListHCPDetail}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Date of Previous Synchronization" value="{!itr.Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Date of Last Synchronization" value="{!itr.Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Days between Synchronization" value="{!itr.Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>


        <apex:pageBlockSection title="HCI/HCO Calls" columns="6">

         <apex:pageBlockTable columns="10" value="{!oIncTranListHCPDetail}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" value="{!itr.Account_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="ABS on Call" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Address" value="{!itr.Account_Location_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Name" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Role" value="{!itr.Attendee_Role_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Detail" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Activity Date" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

         <apex:pageBlock title="">

         </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Pharmacy Calls" columns="4">

         <apex:pageBlockTable columns="10" value="{!oIncTranListHCPDetail}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" value="{!itr.Account_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="ABS on Call" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Address" value="{!itr.Account_Location_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Name" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Role" value="{!itr.Attendee_Role_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Detail" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Activity Date" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>  

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have PDF output using [HTML table tags](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) of this form:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="heading">Sample Type</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!oIncTranListHCPDetail}" var="itr">
    <tr>
        <td class="cell">{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

with CSS defined in a linked CSS static resource that includes definitions such as:

```
td.heading {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #d9edf7;
}
```

that produces correctly colored backgrounds in the PDF output.

Answer (score 1):

In the pageBlockTable you need your background to be painted use css below:

```
background-color:green
```

You can include internal css for this or 
best way is by inline css. This way you can only paint particular table in the page. Example is Below :

```
<apex:pageBlockTable Style="background-color:green;">

.....

</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

I hope this might help you.

Comment: This is okay for apex page but when converting into PDF it does not show. Can you please suggest a way here for pdf?